# Finding Locations of Duplicate data within an Array

Tags: java, arrays

If I have an array like:

int [] numb = {0, 1, 2, 3};

and I want to find the minimum value of the array. I just do a quick easy for loop to find it, but if I have duplicate minimum values, such as:

int [] numb = {0, 1, 0, 2, 3};

How do I find the locations of all the minimum values and how many times it shows up in an array?

If this question has already been asked, I did not find it but feel free to direct me to the proper thread/question.

Comment: I think you're going to have to write a second for-loop to find the number and indices of `min`

Comment: @frickskit not necessarily - see my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does all you want in just one loop. It also doesn't require you to hardcode in an initial 'minimum' value.

```
    int[] values = {6, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 7, 2, 1};
    Integer minimum = null;
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        if(minimum == null || values[i] < minimum)
        {
            minimum = values[i];
            indexes.clear();
            indexes.add(i);
        }
        else if(minimum == values[i])
        {
            indexes.add(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The minimum was: " + minimum);
    System.out.println("It occurred " + indexes.size() + " times in the array");
    System.out.println("Indexes it occured at were: " + Arrays.toString(indexes.toArray(new Integer[]{})));
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks! Now I know how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

when you fined an element dont break from the loop, instead increment a counter to count the number of time it repeats in the array. and keep track of all the places it appeared. Or make your method return the index of were the first element was found, then run the same method again exept at a higher index

Answer (score 0):

```
 int[] array = {0, 1, 0, 2, 3}
 int mininum=999999       //initialize to a number larger than anything in the array would reasonably be
 for (int curr = 0; curr < array.size; curr++) {
     if (array1[curr] < minimum) {
          minimum = array[i];   
     }
 }
 int duplicates = 0;
 for (int i : array){
     if (i == minumum){
         duplicates++;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Does this calculate the minimum value, though?

Comment: this will calculate the minimum value and tell you how many times its repeated. Is that all you need to do? If not, give me a little more info on what you need to accomplish here.

Comment: Hardcoding '999999' might work for trivial examples but isn't incredibly wise. A better step might be Integer.MAX_VALUE, but I think the best way would be to adopt an approach like the one in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Guava library multiset.

If you wont use it, see for example this link 
http://www.zparacha.com/minimum-maximum-array-value/